# PHP echo is printing JavaScript alert code on page

Tags: javascript, php, echo, alert

I was making a form for inserting products for admin in an e-commerce project. During validation of the form data, I tried to check if the form data is empty or not.

Thus I introduced an `if` statement and checked the values of all the parameters passed from the form and in the `if` block wrote an echo statement.

Here is my code:

```
<? php
//text variables
if(isset($_POST['insert_product'])){
    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_status = 'on';
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

    //images variables
    $product_img1 = $FILES['product_img1']['name'];
    $product_img2 = $FILES['product_img2']['name'];
    $product_img3 = $FILES['product_img3']['name'];

    //temp names
    $temp_name1 = $FILES['product_img1']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name2 = $FILES['product_img2']['tmp_name'];
    $temp_name3 = $FILES['product_img3']['tmp_name'];

    //validation and insertion query
    if($product_title == '' OR $product_cat == '' OR $product_brand == '' OR $product_keywords == '' OR $product_img1 == '' OR $product_price == ''){
        echo"<script>alert('you have not entered all the values')</script>";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
```

It is producing an output like

> (...alert('you have not entered all the values');"; exit();} } ....)

Please help me to solve this problem.

I am using Sublime text and checked the same in Notepad++ but it’s giving the same error.

Comment: Try `<?php` instead of `<? php`.

Comment: @MohitChawla Provide a single space in between `echo"<sc` like - `echo "<script>.....";`

Comment: @MohitChawla: Xufox already gave you the solution in his comment. Why are you ignoring it?

Answer (score 0):

try the following, *note semicolon

```
  echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('thanks!');</script>";
```

[image: omitted the rest of code, just printing this line]

Comment: it is printing the sting : alert('thanks!');" ?> on the screen rather then alert of javascript.

Comment: @Mohit Chawla, try just printing the line? I attempted and it seemed to output the alert();

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Try iterating through $_POST in a loop, checking values that way. It'll condense your code and make things easier to read in the future:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($_POST[$key]) || $value == "") {
            echo "<script> alert('you have not entered all the values'); </script>";
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

That said, you should try to preserve $_POST and use a cleaned string if you're using data provided by the user:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST)) {
    // Clean a string, making it safe for using with a database.
    function clean_string($string) {
        global $mysqli;
        $string = $mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
        stripslashes($string);
        return $string;
    }

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!isset($_POST) || $value == "") {
            echo "<script> alert('you have not entered all the values'); </script>";
            exit;
        }

        // If you're going to be using this $_POST data with a database you should also
        // clean the strings before using them in any way.
        $Data = new stdClass();

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] !== "") {
                $Data->$key = clean_string($value);
            }
        }
    }

    // All of the $_POSTed items are set and cleaned for use. Do what you will with them below.
}
```

Comment: now, the ouput is:                                                                                              $value) { if (!isset($_POST[$key]) || $value == "") { echo ""; exit; } } } ?> with a javascript alert. i have tried your upper code. i don know why it is printing this..!!

Comment: I have tested it, and it works. Here's a working [one-page example](http://pastebin.com/46617Hs5).

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo"<script>alert('you have not entered all the values');</script>";
```

use this .....u r forgetting semicon after )